# How to find the log on history of windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

My boss has asked me to find out if a particular user logged in to the domain on a particular date (2/24/2006 to be precise). Is there a resource kit tool, command line utility, or something else that can show me this information?

Answer (score 6):

The security logs of a domain controller record logon events. Unfortunately, a logon from that long ago has probably been rotated out of the log at this point unless you have *extremely* little traffic.

If you use centralized logging, you could retrieve it from there. If not, you're out of luck. The Event IDs that you're looking for are 528 and 4624.